# How to create an Observable inside another Observable to receive part of the data?

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

By subscribing to `getOrderBook` I am getting data via Netty and Websocket. 
The first time a full `OrderBook` arrives, and then incremental updates follow. As a result, I get the complete `OrderBook` with all the changes.
Please tell me how can I create another Observable so that I can receive separately the data that comes in the update (`incrementalUpdateData`) through a subscription?

```
private final Map<Instrument, OrderBook> orderBookMap = new HashMap<>();

  public Observable<OrderBook> getOrderBook(Instrument instrument) {
    return service.subscribeChannel(instrument).flatMap(jsonNode -> {
      if (jsonNode.get("action").asText().equalsIgnoreCase("snapshot")) { //first update - full snapshot
        OrderBook orderBook = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("data"),
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Orderbook.class));
        orderBookMap.put(instrument, orderBook);
        return Observable.just(orderBook);
      } else { //second update and later - incremental update
        OrderBook orderBook = orderBookMap.getOrDefault(instrument, null);
        PublicOrder incrementalUpdateData = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("data").get(0).get("asks"),
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, PublicOrder.class));
        orderBook.update(incrementalUpdateData);
        return Observable.just(orderBook);
      }
    });
  }
```

What do I expect.
`getOrderBook.subscribe(some instrument)` - get full orderBook
`getOrderBookUpdate.subscribe(some instrument)` - get only incremental data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done via [publishsubject](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rxjava/rxjava_publishsubject.htm)
Result code looks like:

```
  private final Map<Instrument, PublishSubject<OrderBookUpdate>> orderBookUpdatesSubscriptions;<br/>
  private final Map<Instrument, OrderBook> orderBookMap = new HashMap<>();

  public Observable<OrderBook> getOrderBook(Instrument instrument) {
    return service.subscribeChannel(instrument).flatMap(jsonNode -> {
      if (jsonNode.get("action").asText().equalsIgnoreCase("snapshot")) { //first update - full snapshot
        OrderBook orderBook = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("data"),
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Orderbook.class));
        orderBookMap.put(instrument, orderBook);
        return Observable.just(orderBook);
      } else { //second update and later - incremental update
        OrderBook orderBook = orderBookMap.getOrDefault(instrument, null);
        PublicOrder incrementalUpdateData = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("data").get(0).get("asks"),
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, PublicOrder.class));
        orderBookUpdatesSubscriptions.computeIfPresent(instrument, (a,b) -> b.onNext(new OrderBookUpdate(incrementalUpdateData)));
        orderBook.update(incrementalUpdateData);
        return Observable.just(orderBook);
      }
    });   }

  public Observable<OrderBookUpdate> getOrderBookUpdates(Instrument instrument) {
    return orderBookUpdatesSubscriptions.computeIfAbsent(instrument, v -> PublishSubject.create());
  }
```